# osmfilter filter for nodes and find the related/nearest street to every node

Tags: openstreetmap

I'm successfully managed to filter all nodes of a specific type by using `osmfilter`:

```
osmfilter austria.o5m --keep="highway=speed_camera"
```

Now I have got a lot of nodes like this:

```xml
<node id="3906966442" lat="48.2975844" lon="14.2988663" version="1" timestamp="2015-12-23T18:18:11Z" changeset="36131585" uid="180830" user="flaimo">
    <tag k="highway" v="speed_camera"/>
    <tag k="maxspeed" v="50"/>
</node>
```

And in the end I'm converting it to a CSV using:

```
osmconvert - --all-to-nodes --csv="@id @lon @lat @timestamp maxspeed"
```

Which works fine. However in addition to the `maxspeed` value I'd also be interested in the name of the street where this node is attached too. Since nodes like `speed_camera` are always attached to a street this should be possible using the Openstreet map dataset.

The only solution I could think of is todo reverse geolocation look up for each node, which however would be very slow. I'd prefer a more performant solution (ideally based on just osmfilter) like keeping all street entries with speed cameras attached in the OSM dataset, but I can't find anyway to do that with osmfilter.

Comment: crosspost: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/49400/osmfilter-all-speed-cameras-with-related-way

Answer (score 4):

> Since nodes like speed_camera are always attached to a street ...

So you mean that a node with tagging for a speed camera is always a child element of a street that it belongs to?
Are you sure?

According to the OSM wiki about [Relation:enforcement](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Relation:enforcement) a speed camera can also be next to the belonging street. The connection is done via a so called [Relation](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Relation) in the OSM data model.

A complete relation for speed cameras has three elements with according roles:
the device, which can be positioned freely,
one node with the from-role and anothe with the to-role.
These two points have to be child element of the belonging way.

So you should get familiar with the OSM data model about relations,
and by finding speed-camera-nodes, you should be able to find the from-and-to nodes, and the parent ay of these two.

Maybe you can use the famous [Overpass API](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API) or [Overpass-turbo](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_turbo) where you can create queries for childs and parents of elements and relations.

I recommend to start with a smaller area for testing your own queries, don't search whole Austria for now.

Read all examples and how-tos about overpass-api and -turbo in the OSM wiki ... there are quite good examples.

Comment: `Are you sure? `, no I'm sorry. You're right it's not the case. But I'll give Overpass API a try. Thank you!

Comment: Someone expert told me that you can reach your aim when using a database for raw OSM data. If still needed, come to OSM forum (German subforum recommended, log in there with your OSM account), and ask there again.